# missing IIS config to run ASP.NET site using Microsoft Identity/AAD?

Tags: model-view-controller, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, iis-express, iis-8

I have a sample C# MVC site, using .Net Framework 4.8, which uses the Microsoft Identity platform/AAD. The sample code is similar to that found here ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api?tabs=visual-studio ), though its framework not .Net Core. and with the WebAPI part removed.

I created the app registration and secret in the Azure portal and added these and the appropriate tenantID to web.config. The app registration is set to allow accounts in the tenant only, set to useg ID Tokens and Redirect URL set to a localhost port.

I can run this site up in Visual Studio 2022 and all works as expected. I can log in using an account on the tenant and all is good.

When I deploy the code to IIS, on the same box and run however, I can't login. I get:

[TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.]
and further down is:
[IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.] - which is just hiding the well-known URL I think.

I wondering if this is a symptom rather than a cause as I know that the well-known config URL (https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration) can be accessed directly so don't believe this is a firewall issue (and the IIS site and VS2022 are running on the same box).

I have used the same basic sample on a site hosted in Azure App Services and again, all is good. I'm wondering if the issue is the IIS configuration, either at a server or site level but can't seem to find anything relevant.

If anyone has any ideas as to what's missing, I'd be very grateful. I'm thinking it can't be much as its working using IIS Express from within VS but...

I've also just tried with this basic sample (https://github.com/AzureAdQuickstarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet) . Similar app registration set up etc and once you log in allows you to see claims. This again works fine in VS2022 but fails with the same error in IIS.

Comment: To work with IIS, you need to create VM in portal and deploy the app into IIS from there.

Comment: Thanks Harshitha, my IIS servers are on prem rather than in Azure - sorry, didn't make that clear above. The site in IIS runs up and the non-authenticated controller methods operate as expected. The issue only occurs when I attempt to login but doesn't get as far as displaying the login page on login.microsoftonline.com

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, this often happens when IIS runs as an account without access to the internet: see [this doc on user accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/understanding-identities). In some IT setups the IIS server must run on a domain joined server to have internet access.

When troubleshooting, start by running the application pool as a domain account, such as your own identity. Run a browser as that user and check you can connect to the discovery endpoint. The application pool identity and the built-in NETWORK SERVICE account should also be able to connect to the internet.

In most real world setups it is usual to deploy a clustered setup. It is then common to run the service as a domain account, which may be easier to administer. This may help when granting permissions to the server resources, such as NTFS files, certificate private keys, decryption keys, or privileged ports. I seem to remember issues otherwise, in our IT setup, when virtual machines were sometimes cloned.

Comment: Thanks Gary - sounds like a plausible explanation for why its working in VS and not in IIS and easy to troubleshoot as you note. Will check it out and let you know - thanks again